# How to add NSOperation QOS .UserInteractive

Tags: swift, cloud, cloudkit, nsoperation

I've been browsing numerous forums and tutorials in the hopes of speeding up my cloudkit app - (at the very least) it seems that the answer comes down to setting the quality of service function to "UserInteractive". At the moment, it takes about 2/3 seconds to update a table controller with 3 records, each with only a string variable, displayed through a label. To my knowledge, setting the qos to be user interactive will force the UI to update faster. However, I am unsure how to properly implement the qos code in its entirety. As it stands, here is my code that takes 2/3 seconds to load.

```
 func fetch()
{   
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)

publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
    else
    {
        for result in results!
        {    
          self.categories.append(result)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in         
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    }
}
     fetch()   
 }
```

therefore, to acheive a quicker UI response, would I be able to implement something like this?

```
 func fetch()
{   
let publicDatabase =     CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)

publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
    else
    {
        for result in results!
        {    
          self.categories.append(result)
        }

        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_UserInteractive
let Queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(Queue, {
print("This is run on the background queue")

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   self.tableView.reloadData()
})
})

    }
    }
}
  fetch()   
}
```

Also, this question was copied from my other account so that I may use a bounty if necessary.

Comment: Jon, the QOS parameter your using here reflects the priority of the processes running on your device, it has no effect on the iCloud operation under pinning it. Less than a second to update something that needs to travel across the cloud is an excellent response and I think your expectations are a little too high.

Comment: After working with the concept, you would be correct.  However (for example), how is that an app like yelp is able to fetch any sort of list or restaurant details so quickly?

Comment: Hi Jon, Sorry 'bout my tardy reply, been away. The fastest way I have managed to make cloud kit work or at least appear to be more snappy is to use cloud kit assets, bundling & then compressing all my data into a single blob, so I get a single read which I than decompress. You can also employ other techniques like pre-fetching and caching data to at least make things seem faster. Focus too on best endeavours perhaps, Yelp in our example, could be silently ranking the list it presents on reviews, maybe its a comprehensive list, maybe not.